# How to force my intercept in my regression to be 0 using the plm package in R?

Tags: r, plm

I am working on a regression where my dependent variable is abnormal earnings growth divided by the book value of equity (AEG_BV) and my independent variable is the lagged version of AEG_BV. I want to force the intercept to be zero which I did with the following code, however my coefficient has not changed after I forced the intercept to be zero. The only thing that changed is that when I ask for a summary of my regression the intercept is not displayed anymore. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code. My data is really long with a lot of different companies and their AEG_BV ranging between 1985 and 2015 but I will provide a short extract of it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plm) 

Table2overall <- data.frame (Company_name = c("Alpharma", "Alpharma", "Alpharma", "American Airlines", "American Airlines", "American Airlines"),
Year = c(1985, 1986, 1987, 2002, 2003, 2004),
AEG_BV = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.045, 0.007, 0.003, 0.001))

Table2overall <- Table2overall %>%
  group_by(Company_name) %>%
  mutate(AEG_BVlag = dplyr::lag(AEG_BV))

pdata_Table2overall <- pdata.frame(Table2overall,
                               index = c("Company_name", "Data_Year"))

regression_Table2overall <- plm(AEG_BV ~ 0 + AEG_BVlag,
                            data = pdata_Table2overall)

summary(regression_Table2overall)
```

My output is the following with intercept and then without intercept:

```
Regression overall market 
========================================
                 Dependent variable:    
             ---------------------------
                       AEG_BV           
----------------------------------------
AEG_BVlag             -0.03***          
                       (0.005)          
                                        
Constant               0.07***          
                       (0.01)           
                                        
----------------------------------------
Observations           29,305           
R2                      0.002           
Adjusted R2             0.002           
F Statistic   46.35*** (df = 1; 29303)  
========================================
Note:        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01



Regression overall market 
===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                              AEG_BV           
-----------------------------------------------
AEG_BVlag                    -0.03***          
                              (0.005)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                  29,305           
R2                             0.001           
Adjusted R2                    0.001           
Residual Std. Error      1.14 (df = 29304)     
F Statistic          39.65*** (df = 1; 29304)  
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

I am thankful for any type of guidance!

Comment: It will be useful if you include both outputs. And even better if you include the data, and the libraries used so the code is reproducible.

Comment: @RicVillalba, the question and tag references the [`plm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/index.html) package. It's likely safe to infer `dplyr` based on the use of `dplyr::lag` and magrittr's `%>%` pipe. I agree that sample data and expected output are important.

Comment: There's no `lm` function in the `plm` package, though

Comment: I edited my question and now I have both of the outputs included that were produced and a sample data. Yes, it is plm not lm, I just tried the regression out with that one too and forgot to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for argument `model` in `plm()` is `model = "within"`. Thus, in case argument `model`, is not specified, the functions sets `model = "within"` automatically; this is standard R behaviour.

This is what your code example for the model estimation with `plm` points to. However, the output you supply is not the usual `summary` output of a `plm` model object; also it shows that you have an intercept in one model and no intercept in another model but you do not show how these models were estimated. So, it is really hard to help you given the code and output does not match.

A hint would be to look at both models estimated with more digits. The output you supply is by some fancy tabluating package (maybe `stargazer`?) and we can see from the model statistics that the models diverge to some extend while the coefficents given the precision printed seem to be the same.

Try something like this to check the coefficents in more detail:

```
print(summary(plm_model1), digits = 10)
print(summary(plm_model2), digits = 10)
```

So much for the programming part of the answer. Some statistical background regards the within model:
A within model (= fixed effect model) does not have an intercept per se; any good econometrics textbook will treat that topic: the intercept gets `demeaned` out. However, there is a way to get the same coeffiecient estimates and an intercept. In `plm` package, this can be achieved by the `within_intercept` function. Usage and references to the statistical background are given in the help to this function (`?within_intercept`).

Comment: I was using the model = "pooling" and that's where I encountered the problem that the coefficient is not changing whether I have an intercept or not which seems unlikely for me. Does it mean if I use the model = "within" this wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Well the code supplied showed you estimated a within model. And the output you supplied does not fit to the example code. Really hard to help you given this disconnect. I updated/extended my answer and maybe that helps.